# Rails: def admin_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I define admin_user if I have this code in my controller:

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end
helper_method :admin_user
```

admin_user must be a user with id 1.

I want to use something like this:

```
<% if admin_user %> content for admin only< %elsif current_user%> content for admin and other logged in users <% end %>
```

ps. I don't want to use CanCan or other gems.

Comment: Isn't this a bit of a smell?

Why not have a boolean admin flag on the user model? That way you can have more than one admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
# checks to see if current_user exists, and if so, has id 1
def admin_user?
  current_user && current_user.id == 1
end
```

Comment: And additional thanks for the logic explanation, it's useful for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
def admin_user
  current_user.try(:id) == 1
end
```

should work but, IMHO, it isn't very nice.

Comment: I have just tried it because your question put me in doubt. By the way, it works fine...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in your user model:

```
def is_admin?
  self.user_id == 1
end
```

Then, you can call something like

> current_user.is_admin?

Comment: Thank you, but I wanted something else (I saw this in related) :)